# Android Database Sqlite SQLiteException

Tags: java, android-studio

I have this is the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COL_1 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT COL_1 FROM registeruser WHERE  COL_2  =?  and  COL_3  =?
```

and this is my code:

```
String [] columns={"COL_1"};
        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        String selection=" COL_2 " + " =? " + " and " + " COL_3 "+ " =? ";
        String [] selectionArgs={username,password};
        Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null,null,null);
        int count=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does the table called `TABLE_NAME` have a column called `COL_1` in it? What are the columns of `TABLE_NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is obvious. The error message tells you that the table `registeruser` contains no column `COL_1`. You cannot retrieve a column that does not exist. Check what are you going to retrieve from the database.

Comment: I suggest you not think about *what needs to be changed*. First think of what do you want from this program - do you want it to select some data? What data? From what table? From what column? Only when you know what you need you can think how to implement it in the code.

Comment: If you want *that the table registeruser to contain a column "COL_1"*, then add this column to this table.